# Why is Instancing a class that is inside a loaded swf ignoring timeline content on this class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two fla:   main.fla  and info.fla

info.fla has a class defined (src.com.objects.FriendListItem) on a movieclip inside the library.

When playing info.fla alone, the movieclip (FriendListItem) loads great (with its timeline contents).
When loading info.swf into main.fla the class is created but all timeline content is not there (therefore getting tons of errors for textfields and movieclips not being present)

Im totally lost, I'm loading using loaderMax like so:

```
private var queue:LoaderMax = new LoaderMax({name:"mainQueue", onComplete:completeHandler}); 
queue.append(new SWFLoader("swf/FriendsInvite.swf", { name:"FriendsInvite" }))
queue.load();

private function completeHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void 
{  
    friendsInvite = LoaderMax.getContent("FriendsInvite").rawContent;
    addChild(friendsInvite);
    friendsInvite.init(); 
}
```

and on the init() on friends invite:

```
var theName:String = "Joe";
public function init():void {
    var friend:FriendListItem = new FriendListItem();
    this.addChild(friend); 
    friend["txtName"].text=theName;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution]
Hi, 
The problem was that the classes where being loaded from the main class first without the inner swf being loaded, that caused the first classes to become priority, so instancing was just leaving an empty timeline.

I created subprojects for each of the loaded swf that caused this class issue, and made the classes unique to them, that way when loading the swf, the classes are created with the loaded swf, and respecting the content

hope it helps anyone!